# Python selenium extract data from table and click

Tags: python, selenium, web, click, web-crawler

Dear stackoverflow community,

I recently ran into trouble trying to extract data from:

```
https://www2.sgx.com/securities/corporate-information?country=SINGAPORE
```

My purpose is to click each link in the table, starting from 3CNERGY LIMITED, which opens up another webpage tab, extract that, close that tab after extracting, go back to the main page, and click the next link.

My issues are: 
unable to find the element that lets me loop thru the table and 
unable to switch from main webpage to tab and then back.

My progress:
i thought

```
<sgx-table-list data-rendered-rows="20" data-visible-rows="10" style="min-width: 560px; transform: translateY(0px);" data-rendered-index="0" data-visible-index="0" xpath="1">
```

would allow me to loop thru the table but the len returns 1 only..

i've been able to click the first webpage using:

```
CE = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'infopub')]")
```

but without being able to loop thru the table, the script just performs the first click. Also, i cant change it to find elements by xpath because it becomes a list and .click() doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and give the following a try. I used [XPath Helper Wizard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper-wizard/jadhpggafkbmpdpmpgigopmodldgfcki) which is an addon for chrome.

Main Table from Link: (change the sgx-table-row[**RowNumberHere**] to loop through companies in Column 1)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//sgx-table-row[1]/sgx-table-cell-link[contains(@class, 'sgx-table-cell')]").click()
```

Inside the Company link Link: (Change /tr[**RowNumberHere**] to your variable for looping)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[contains(@class, 'basicInfoContentContainerRight')]")
```

Going Back a Page:

```
driver.back()
```

Comment: use driver.back()

Comment: Hi william, i am using this code. However, on the first page i am unable to click the  5 link (Abterra) for some reason, and on the second page unable to click the first. code:        for i in range(0,100):
        click = "//sgx-table-row[{0}]/sgx-table-cell-link[contains(@class, 'sgx-table-cell')]".format(i + 1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(click).click()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='ctl07_secretary1Label']").text)
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward. The flow should go like this:

1. Navigate to the page
2. Close the popup dialog
3. Wait for the data to be loaded
4. Loop through the company links clicking each link, getting data from the new tab, closing the new tab, switch back to the main window

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www2.sgx.com/securities/corporate-information?country=SINGAPORE"
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# close the preview warning dialog
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#beta-warning-dialog button"))).click()

# wait for the data to be loaded
company_name_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table-container a")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(companyNameLocator))

main_window_handle = driver.current_window_handle
# loop through visible company links
links = list(filter(lambda e: e.is_displayed(), driver.find_elements(companyNameLocator)))
for link in links
    link.click()

    # wait for new tab to open
    wait.until(lambda d: len(d.window_handles) == 2)
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

    # scrape something off the page
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.ID, "ctl07_lblCompName")).text)

    # close the current tab
    driver.close()

    # wait for the tab to be closed and switch back to the main tab
    wait.until(lambda d: len(d.window_handles) == 1)
    driver.switch_to_window(main_window_handle)
```

Comment: edit: getting this error:Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/anthonygoh/Desktop/Data science/Useful code/SGX.py", line 28, in <module> for e in filter(lambda e: e.is_displayed(), driver.find_elements(companyNameLocator)): Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Comment: Sorry, I can't test this right now. I made some adjustments... try now?